# Issue with Dice Rolling Program

Tags: python, indentation, dice

I have to do a dice rolling program for my Computers Class. I chose to write mine in Python. However, when I execute it, it prints the list of numbers 1000 times. Here's the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`

```
import random
def rollDie():
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0 
    eleven = 0
    twelve = 0
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        roll = int(random.randint(1,6)) + (random.randint(1,6))
        if roll == 2:
            two = two+1
        elif roll == 3:
            three = three+1
        elif roll == 4:
            four = four+1
        elif roll == 5:
            five = five+1
        elif roll == 6:
            six = six+1
        elif roll == 7:
           seven = six+1
        elif roll == 8:
           eight = eight+1 
        elif roll == 9:
           nine = nine+1 
        elif roll == 10:
           ten = ten+1
        elif roll == 11:
           eleven = eleven+1
        elif roll == 12:
           twelve = twelve+1
    print "2:%s" % two
    print "3:%s" % three
    print "4:%s" % four
    print "5:%s" % five
    print "6:%s" % six
    print "7:%s" % seven
    print "8:%s" % eight
    print "9:%s" % nine
    print "10:%s" % ten
    print "11:%s" % eleven
    print "12:%s" % twelve
rollDie()
```

`

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you've got a bug here: `seven = six+1`. I think you want `seven + 1` there.

Comment: Also, the program, run exactly as you posted it here, only prints the list of numbers once.

Comment: @dano is correct, I just ran it as well. Python27, Win7.

Comment: Are you sure? Because for me, when I type in terminal "python Dice.py" it returns the list 1000 times.

Comment: 100% sure! I wonder if you're using tabs in your text editor, rather than spaces, and that's causing the indentation as interpreted by Python to be different than what you see in your file. Try converting all tabs to spaces in your .py file and try again.

Comment: Yup. I don't know what exactly is different in your file but this version you've pasted works as intended.

Comment: Thank you. I was using spaces. I am a little new to python, and your advice is appreciated.

Comment: This code just screams use a list. Ignore this comment if you have not covered lists yet, or it is forbidden for this problem. But using a list, it would be much shorter as well as easier to simulate rolling 10 dice at a time.

Comment: Yes, it is really bad to use named variables like that. Either use a list of size 12 or a dictionary with the integers 2 to 12 as keys...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your indenting in your text editor is off; the print statements are encompassed by the `for` loop. You also have a little problem, you call `seven = six+1`. Here is your edited code, try pasting **this** into your file instead:

```
import random
def rollDie():
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0 
    eleven = 0
    twelve = 0
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        roll = int(random.randint(1,6)) + (random.randint(1,6))
        if roll == 2:
            two = two+1
        elif roll == 3:
            three = three+1
        elif roll == 4:
            four = four+1
        elif roll == 5:
            five = five+1
        elif roll == 6:
            six = six+1
        elif roll == 7:
           seven = seven+1
        elif roll == 8:
           eight = eight+1 
        elif roll == 9:
           nine = nine+1 
        elif roll == 10:
           ten = ten+1
        elif roll == 11:
           eleven = eleven+1
        elif roll == 12:
           twelve = twelve+1
    print "2:%s" % two
    print "3:%s" % three
    print "4:%s" % four
    print "5:%s" % five
    print "6:%s" % six
    print "7:%s" % seven
    print "8:%s" % eight
    print "9:%s" % nine
    print "10:%s" % ten
    print "11:%s" % eleven
    print "12:%s" % twelve
rollDie()
```

Also, your code is extremely inefficient; try using the following code instead:

```
import random
rolls = {}
for k in range(2, 13):
        rolls[k] = 0

for k in range(1000):
        roll = random.randint(1, 6)+random.randint(1, 6)
        rolls[roll]+=1

for k in rolls:
        print '%d occurred %d times!' %(k, rolls[k])
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$
2 occurred 38 times!
3 occurred 51 times!
4 occurred 90 times!
5 occurred 99 times!
6 occurred 136 times!
7 occurred 173 times!
8 occurred 151 times!
9 occurred 90 times!
10 occurred 92 times!
11 occurred 58 times!
12 occurred 22 times!
bash-3.2$
```

If we time our programs, here is your time:

```
This ran in 0.06672 seconds!
```

And here is mine:

```
This ran in 0.004228 seconds!
```

Of course, this may be just my computer giving such a great difference :). If you were wondering how I timed it, I used `time.time() - previous time.time()`.

Answer (score 0):

without variables and we can achieve same function of roll dice in same way:

```
import random
    from collections import Counter,OrderedDict


    def ran(i):
        roll = int(random.randint(1,6)) + (random.randint(1,6))
        return roll

    for i,j in OrderedDict(Counter(map(ran,range(1,1000)))).items():
        print i,":", j
```

Explanation: first we store all values of rand int in dict.map links the method ran .
then usinf counter v can find all the frequences  then odered dict is used to sort according to the key ie first no.of 2's and so on.